# I want to run a tkinter script on startup without desktop

Tags: gui

I've seen solutions for non-PI situations to start the x-11 server without loading the desktop.  I want to boot straight into my Python script that uses tkinter for the gui.  I've found out that you need the x-11 running to draw the graphics.  Is there a solution to this for the Raspberry Pi??  My app is full screen and when you switch windows you can see the desktop.  Also, the only thing I want the end user to ever see is the app.  No desktop, no internet, nothing.  Is there a distro for the pi that does this?

I've started porting the app to use Kivy instead of tkinter and it's been horrible.  I don't grasp the Kivy way of doing things.  The only thing the app does is use the gpio ports to return temp values and switches between 4 screens.  Should be very simple....sigh.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this. You just need an X window manager running in place of a full desktop environment. I use *openbox* on my Raspberry Pi for exactly this purpose. I have the RPi configured to automatically log in as the Pi user on boot. On login, the pi user's bash shell reads the ~/.bashrc script and launches X via startx. X is configured to use openbox as the window manager. When launched, openbox reads commands from ~pi/.config/openbox/autostart. From there, I call my python script.

The (plain) X desktop will still be visible when you switch between apps (e.g. using Alt-Tab) but there won't be any spurious icons or docks. You can probably work around this if you really want to. I [launch the FocusWriter app full screen, then shut down when it exits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7r6CtPqOu0).

Comment: Thanks Bob!  This sounds very much like what I'd like to do.  For clarification, what distro are you using?  IE. raspbian?  I'm sorry if this sounds newbie-ish, but I am new to linux in general.  I would like to use a very very minimal OS for the PI due to boot times and memory usage.  I'm assuming I use a raspian-like image, disable the starting of the desktop and tell it to start openbox instead.  If you know of a good tutorial or write-up on this, I would be very appreciative!!  I'd vote up your answer already but I don't have the rep yet.  Also, will this impact the GPIO ports at all?

Comment: Yes, Raspbian. I should have mentioned that. I am considering migrating to diet-pi, a minimal distribution, then rebuilding my project on that.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have downloaded a minimal Raspbian image since last post and installed xorg and openbox.  I'm having a weird issue that when I type startx now, I get a black GUI (mouse moves with a crosshair pointer) but the top left corner of the screen is a bash prompt!  It behaves just as normal bash.  Can't right click and get any menus or middle click.  I haven't messed with the xinit file yet, just wanted to run openbox.  Ever seen THAT before?  Google hasn't haha.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to impact GPIO in any way. There are many variations in how to configure X, but I simply created **~/.xinitrc** (/home/pi/.xinitrc for the pi user) and put **openbox &** in it to launch openbox. The black GUI you are seeing is, I suspect, the result of not having launched a window manager. If you are seeing an xterm window when you launch startx, just type in **openbox &** (ampersand to background it) to test. Note that you can use a mix of .xinitrc and ~/.config/autostart, depending on whether you want things to start only under openbox or any X session.

Comment: Thanks again Bob!  Turns out that openbox never really installed correctly.  I reinstalled it and now it's working fine.